# Storing and showing mobile emoticons on html5 webapp

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile, web-applications

I am running a HTML5 mobile App where users can create accounts.

It often happens that users use special mobile emoticons in their names. These are stored in my mysql Database as ?? and therefore show up in on my webapp as such.

The names are gathered on the client with javascript and sent to my server (which is written in java) which stores the Strings in my mysql database.

---

My question is:

Is there a way how I can store and show those emojis or do I have to make clear to the user that only standard chars are allowed?